# mongodb - keeping track of aggregated documents

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a mongodb collection that stores raw information coming from an app. I wrote a multi-pipeline aggregation method to generate more meaningful data from the raw documents.
Using the $out operator in my aggregation function I store the aggregation results in another collection.

I would like to be able to either delete raw documents that were already aggregated, or somehow mark those documents so I know not to aggregate again.

I am worried that I cannot guaranty I won't miss out some documents that are created in between or create duplicate aggregated documents.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: An aggregation cannot affect the documents it acts on, so you can't mark them as part of the application. The simplest thing to do is to remember when you did an aggregation and only aggregate more recent documents. Really though, there's just not enough information to know exactly what you're trying to do so I can't give definite answers.

Comment: I log a system's events in a very raw way into a collection. It is imperative for me to group them together for them to be meaningful. However, doing it at runtime would require too many searches. So instead i just shove all the information into a collection and then, when needed, aggregate the results. I would like to aggregate only once, and store the results in another collection, and I want to be able to mark the last document that was aggregated. Your suggestion to use a timestamp seems like a good idea, I will look into it. I was hoping for something simpler, though